# Justification for the inclusion of triangle inequality in the definition of a metric

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

How does one justify that triangle inequality must be included in the definition of a metric?

Well I know the geometric reason that it was motivated from seeing the geometry in R2,R3 etc,but are there any other reasons?

For example if I'm teaching a student who is seeing metrics for the first time how do I justify it to him that triangle inequality must be included in the definition other than geometry?

Any insights or thoughts regarding this would be helpful.

Is it something got to do with the length of shortest path or something?

Comment: [Not an answer to your question, just an FYI.] Apparently a metric without the triangle inequality is called a [semimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Semimetrics).

Comment: Related question on MO: [Why the triangle inequality?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65513/why-the-triangle-inequality)

Comment: Now if the triangle inequality wasn't included then the distance between two elements wouldn't be the shortest distance right?I hope what I'm thinking is correct

Comment: I explain the triangle inequality by saying that if you are going from one place to another and stop somewhere else before completing the trip you can't make the trip shorter.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The inclusion of the triangle inequality is justified by the fact that it holds in the familiar examples and is used frequently in working with them. It is rather the **omission** of the triangle inequality (leading to so-called semimetrics) that is in need of justification to show that the additional generality is good for something.

Comment: Ok,if the triangle inequality would be omitted from the definition what would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) gives an intuitive meaning of each of the three axioms that define a metric space:

> Ignoring mathematical details, for any system of roads and terrains
> the distance between two locations can be defined as the length of the
> shortest route connecting those locations. To be a metric there
> shouldn't be any one-way roads. The triangle inequality expresses the
> fact that detours aren't shortcuts. If the distance between two points
> is zero, the two points are indistinguishable from one-another.